# HL7 Data Type Error

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, hl7, hl7-v2

I have an ORU R01 version 2.4 message that I'm trying to get through, but for some reason, it keeps giving me a data type error on the receive side. Below is the message:

```
MSH|^~\&|HMED|DMC|||20110527104101||ORU^R01|M-TEST05|P|2.4|
PID|1|333333333|000009999999||MTEST^MALEPAT5^L^""|""|19900515|M|""|2||||||S|PRO|9999999995|333333333|""||
PV1|1|E|ED^OFF UNIT^OFFUNIT^02|1|||070706^TestDoc^Edward^S^""^""||||||||||||9999999995||||||||||||||||||||DMC|||||20110526231400|20110701014900||||||||
ORC|RE|339999-333333333-1-77777|339999-333333333-1-77777||||||||||
OBR|1|339999-333333333-1-77777|339999-333333333-1-77777|ED HP|||20110527003054|||||||||||||77777^MedVa Chart|77777-RES333333333-339999-1-9999999995|
OBX|1|FT|ED HP||~Depaul Medical Center - Norfolk, VA 23505~~Patient: MALEPAT5 L MEDVATEST DOB: 5/15/1990~~MR #: 333333333 Age/Gender: 21y M~~DOS: 5/26/2011 23:14 Acct #: 9999999995~~Private Phys: Patient denies having a primary    ED Phys: Edward S. TestDoc, NP-C~              care physician.~~CHIEF COMPLAINT: Enc. Type: ACUITY:~~Sore throat Initial 4_Level 4~~HISTORY OF PRESENT ILLNESS ~Note~~Medical screening exam initiated: May 26, 2011 00:36~~HPI text: 21 year old male to the emergency room with a c/o sore throat pain~for the past week. Pt denies cough, N\T\V, diarrhea, and fever.~~Approximate time of injury/onset of symptoms 1 week(s) ago~~Medical and surgical history obtained.~~PAST HISTORY ~Past Medical/Surgical History~~ The history is provided by the patient~~ The patient's pertinent past medical history is as follows: Obesity~~ The patient's pertinent past surgical history is as follows: None~~ Patient allergies: No known allergies.~~ Home medications: Ibuprofen PO~~ The medication history was obtained from: verbally from the patient~~At the time of this signature, I have reviewed and agree with documented Past~History, Home Medications, Allergies, Social History and Family History.~~Past Social History~~Patient does not use tobacco.~~Patient does not use alcohol.~~Patient does not use drugs.~~EXAM ~CONSTITUTIONAL: Alert, in no apparent distress; well-developed;~well-nourished.~HEAD: Normocephalic, atraumatic~EYES: PERRL; EOM's intact.~ENTM: Nose: no rhinorrhea; Throat: no erythema or exudate, mucous membranes~moist. The bilateral tonsils are edematous and the uvula is mildly enlarged.~No exudates are noted. the tonsils do not touch.~Neck: No JVD, supple without lymphadenopathy~RESP: Chest clear, equal breath sounds.~CV: S1 and S2 WNL; No murmurs, gallops or rubs.~GI: Normal bowel sounds, abdomen soft and non-tender. No masses or~organomegaly.~GU: No costo-vertebral angle tenderness.~BACK: Non-tender~UPPER EXT: Normal inspection~LOWER EXT: No edema, no calf tenderness. Distal pulses intact.~NEURO: CN intact, reflexes 2/4 and sym, strength 5/5 and sym, sensation~intact.~SKIN: No rashes; Normal for age and stage.~PSYCH: Alert and oriented, normal affect.~~Printed By User N. Interface on 5/27/2011 12:30 AM~~Discharge Summary~~||||||S|
```

And here are the error messages I'm getting:

```
Error happened in body during parsing

Error # 1
Segment Id: PV1_PatientVisit
Sequence Number: 1
Field Number: 52
Error Number: 102
Error Description: Data type error
Encoding System: HL7nnnn　

Error # 2
Segment Id: OBR_ObservationRequest
Sequence Number: 1
Field Number: 20
Error Number: 102
Error Description: Data type error
Encoding System: HL7nnnn
```

I have ensured that my party is set up properly and that Validate Body Segments is unchecked and Allow Trailing delimiters is checked.

Comment: HL7 members are looking to use StackOverflow for more of its support queries. To aide that could someone create a hl7-v2 tag and use it for this question.

Comment: @BENBUNCoder Late admittedly, but done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been resolved. I ended up having to customize the segment and data type schemas in order to resolve the two errors above. The segment schema needed to be altered to add another field at the end of the PV1 segment in order to accept the last field. The OBR20 needed to reference a custom data type that took in two strings in order to process properly